# HealthKit requestAuthorization dialog not appearing

Tags: ios, healthkit

I have been consistently unable to get the HealthKit requestAuthorization dialog to appear. This has been the case for two different phones with different OS versions and different installation methods (see below). The requestAuthorization code is standard boilerplate code, such as:

```
HKCharacteristicType *genderType = [HKObjectType characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex];
[self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil readTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects: genderType, nil] completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"requestAuthorization completion block");
}];
```

I've tried a fresh app with just that code, tried different parameters for the requestAuthorization method call, and have tried resetting our systems in a number of different ways: app uninstall, resetting settings, erasing phone content and setting with existing partial backup; erasing phone content and settings with a full backup, erasing content and settings and starting phone as a new phone. Have tried multiple different readTypes and shareTypes. Each time requestAuthorization is called on a fresh app install, the following error code appears:

> "Error occurred = Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing
>   com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement." UserInfo=0x7fa748534b00
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit
>   entitlement.}"

However, the HealthKit entitlements are set in both Capabilities on xcode as well as Capabilities in the App ID on Apple Developer: Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles.

*- Questions:* **How do I fix this issue so the requestAuthorization dialog appears? What is a possible cause of phones getting into a state where they get this error consistently?**

*- Phones used:* iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus
*- OS Versions used:* iOS 9.0 / 9.0.2 / 9.1 / 9.2
*- Methods of loading app onto phone:* iOS App Store, Watch App App Store, TestFlight, xcode
*- Situations where this appears to not be broken:* With our users' (non-development) phones installing via the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

A few things could be causing this. First, your provisioning profiles could be out of date with what you are actually seeing on the web portal. Try refreshing these manually from XCode.

Does your app have an app extension or watchOS app that uses the HealthKit framework? Each of extension/watch app will have their own profiles on the web portal, and if the HealthKit framework has been added to any of them without having the entitlement added as well then this could also cause the error.